# Python: iteration of column values by reading excel sheet

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have got an excel sheet with 500 rows with 3 columns
qryid ( values would be 307199470995891  ( unique values) )
WLID ( values would be 1001        ( duplicates could be there )
SQL Query :  select statements with max varchar length of 10000

I have to execute the qry on a Teradata database for benchmarking.. i convert into csv file ( formating the SQLquery column to remove the newline) before connecting to the DB to load the data into a table.

```
mydf = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Qry1.xlsx')
mydf.to_csv (r'C:\Users\Qry1.csv', index = None, header=True)
mytddf = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Qry1.csv')
for index_label, row_series in mytddf.iterrows():
    mytddf.at[index_label , 'SQL'] = row_series['SQL'].replace("\n"," ")
    mytddf.to_csv(r'C:\Users\Qry1_format.csv',index=False,header=False)
```

Issue i face is my qryid column data get converted to 30719947E+7 .

How can i retain the formatting or can i do the same in excel without converting to CSV?

thanks
KN

Comment: Are they written in the scientific format (the format of `123E+X` is called scientific) in the CSV, or only after loading the CSV in Excel?

Comment: the actual value is in the excel sheet is reported correctly but upon saving it as .csv file then that value turns into scientific notation.

Comment: How do i ignore the header in the file?

wb = load_workbook(filename = r'NO-Access-Queries-Wave2_3_1028.xlsx')
ws = wb['Sheet1']
for col in ws['D']:
    #print(col.value)
    pd.read_sql(col.value,mysession)

Comment: Just slice the column: `[1:]`